# Deploy windows 8.1 store apps

Tags: deployment, windows-8.1

I have to continu the work of an intern, working on windows 8.1 store application.

For the context, I am a very beginner with windows 8.1 OS, and also with windows 8.1 app dev... So at the moment, I don't know, what informations you will need to help me, and that's annoying, so please tell me if I miss anything.

So, I tried first, to install what he does.

In the debug folder, I found some app.exe, so I tried them and got the message "the app must be in a app container" (in french, I can only translate in english, I don't know if it's the same in the english Windows...).

So, I tried something else, deploy the application with Visual studio, but I don't find any results in the project folder...

It is an app that is meant for an enterprise, so there is no need to deploy it in the windows store.

How can I deploy it, so I can install the application myself, on all the desks easily?

I found [this](http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-windows-8-apps-without-storewindows-8/), but cannot find any .appx file .

Comment: Right click the project in Solution Explorer, you will find "Store" in the context menu, select "Create App Packages", follow the instructions, and the final output is the .appx file and a script to install it (Add-AppDevPackage.ps1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 blogs were written for Windows 8. I have done before but not sure if still correct for 8.1;

Steps for deploying on a device (with screenshots)

[How Do I Deploy a Windows 8 App to Another Device for Testing?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2012/11/05/how-do-i-deploy-a-windows-8-app-to-another-device-for-testing.aspx)

Distribute apps to business customers

[Deploying Metro style apps to businesses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Executing with powershell, I got this error : A user already installed a uncompressed version of this app. Cannot replace by a package version" . But I cannot find it. I have the administrator permission. What should I do?

Comment: The "uncompressed version" was installed by Visual Studio when you debugged it previously. It can be easily uninstalled: go to Start screen, and navigate to "Apps" page, select the tile, and right click->uninstall. Screenshot from here http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=60

Comment: That's what I check first. But nothing. Do I need to delete all what's on bin folder? I got ARM, debug, release, x64, x86...

Comment: Do you mean you could not find the app in Start screen->Apps? Did you tried Searching it?

Comment: Yes, that whas because I had to uninstall it, with the right user. Thank you.